# JSON из Javascript - имена не заключены в двойные кавычки

Tags: json, delphi

Скачиваю HTML/JS, и там есть json-текст.
Delphi (Tokyo) его отказывается парсить, т.к. такой JSON некорректный.
У Javascript есть спец. функция, которая превращает такой некорректный JSON-текст в корректный.
Есть ли такое в Delphi?

визуально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В JS это функция stringify

Comment: Приведите пример такого некорректного JSON в вопросе плиз (кнопка "править")

Comment: что интересно за функция такая в js

Comment: Ну, это совершенно не json. Попытаться преобразовать в json в принципе можно, но геморрой

Comment: То есть к вам приходит вот такой JSON только без кавычек?

Comment: да, для javascript  это нормально, т.к. javascript умеет потом правильно это преобразовать в json-объект

Comment: >>Ну, это совершенно не json.
Очень даже json, только имена без кавычек, т.е. нужно писать функцию по добавлению кавычек.

Comment: @Akella225 аххах. формат есть формат. если в формате укзаано что имена полей - в кавычках, значит они в кавычках. Если кавычек нет, значит формату не соответствует.  Более того, конструкция `!0` тоже явно не из этой оперы.

Comment: >>формат есть формат
Ещё раз: в JS строки json передаются вот так, да.

Comment: Кстати, формат JSON5 допускает без кавычек: Ключи объекта могут быть без кавычек, если они являются валидными идентификаторами ECMAScript 5.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81

Comment: это не строка json в js, это просто JS-объект. а `stringify` всего лишь сериализует его в JSON-строку, без всяких там коррекций.

Comment: Я догадался. Осталось это реализовать в Delphi.